# js reverse while loop

Tags: javascript, while-loop

i'm trying to make do...while loop with reversed order and with "random step".

```
var estam = 100;
do
{

   //   some things, that can change variable "rd"

   estam -= Math.floor((Math.random()*rd)+1)
}
while (estam < 1);
```

But browsers just perform `do` once.

I'm trying to get: "do something with `some things` and decrease variable `estam` accordingly to those things (and those some operations) as long as `estam` is bigger than zero".

Or i need to make ordinary loop with steps, and in each step check `estam` than jump out to function and back ?

Comment: If you want it to loop while estam is bigger than zero, you should specify that in the while condition as estam > 0. What you have now is not equivalent to what you say you want.

Comment: I thought that last line `while (estam < 1);` is the conditional limit to break te loop. My mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The do while expression should be read as "do this work while this expression is true".

You are looking for

```
while (estam > 0);
```

which will ensure the loop breaks once estam is less than 0, when the expression is no longer true.

Comment: So simple, I thought that last line `while (estam < 1);` is the conditional limit to break te loop.